# Theoretical Results of Optimization Algorithms on Non-Convex and "Noisy" Functions

Tags: neural-networks, optimization, gradient-descent

Have any major results been established on the use of gradient descent for optimizing non-convex and noisy functions?

It seems like the majority of the desirable properties of gradient based optimization algorithms are intended for convex and well defined functions.

But does anyone know if these same gradient based optimization functions make any claims about their performance on non-convex and noisy functions (e.g. when we only have discrete realizations available from the target function)?

I found a reference here http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs6787/2017fa/Lecture7.pdf (page 34) which seems to indicate that in theory, gradient descent can be used on non-convex functions - but I can't really find anything clear-cut online.

Does anyone know if any convergence results have been established surrounding gradient descent on non-convex functions? Or is this still open territory?

Does anyone have any ideas about this?

Thanks!

Comment: Specifically for gradient descent, since it is a deterministic algorithm, it might not work well for non-convex problems. Hence why stochastic gradient descent was developed, to partially deal with this issue, in a fashion similar to all other heuristics.

Comment: thank you for your reply! i always wondered about this - what reasons do we have to believe that suggests that the "loss functions" in machine learning are non-convex? do we just "assume this fact" because the loss functions are in many dimensions and complex in nature, thus they are more likely to be non-convex than convex? I thought that stochastic gradient descent is meant to accelerate the optimization process - was stochastic gradient descent (SGD) developed to address the non-convexity of loss functions? how exactly is SGD helping in dealing with the non-convex aspect? thank you so much!

Comment: would you happen to know if stochastic gradient descent helps in optimizing "noisy functions"?

Comment: if you are interested - you can check out this question I posted over here! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4358737/can-we-tell-if-any-function-is-convex-or-non-convex thank you so much!